# AWS SNS: Not sending sms to phone number

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I am trying a small demo for sending SMS to numbers here in India. I used following code snippet but not working.

```
public void send(String to, String textBody) {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
    awsCredentials = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);

    PublishResult result = snsClient
            .publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(textBody)
                    .withPhoneNumber("+9195355*****"));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I am not able to figure out what is missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it work if you try it from the AWS CLI? `aws sns publish --phone-number +9195355xxx --message foo`

Comment: I didn’t try cli, but it works with console.

Comment: That's very strange if it works with the CLI and the same phone number. Are you getting back any errors? Are they both using the same set of credentials? Can you try sending to a different phone number (preferably from a different phone company)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've confirmed that sending SMS using the SNS console,the messages are delivered successfully then this seems to suggest that there could be an issue with the provided code snippet!

I've modified your code snippet slightly and I've confirmed the following code snippet to be working without issues :

```or-tag-here
public static void main(String[] args) {

ProfileCredentialsProvider creds = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("syumaK");
AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(creds).withRegion("us-east-1").build();

String textBody = "My test SMS message from SNS";
String to = "+0123456789";

send(snsClient, to, textBody);
}

public static void send(AmazonSNS snsClient, String to, String textBody) {

try {
        PublishResult result = snsClient
                .publish(new PublishRequest()
                        .withMessage(textBody)
                        .withPhoneNumber(to));

        System.out.println(result);
        LOGGER.info("Message send with id {}."+ result.getMessageId());

} catch (AmazonSNSException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Got an exception. " + e.getMessage())
}
}
```

Troubleshooting Steps:

-If using ***ProfileCredentialsProvider*** works just like above, consider switching back to ***EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider*** or using ***BasicAWSCredentials*** provider and check if you observe any success/failure?

I have tested the above code snippet using the following environment spec:

```or-tag-here
OS : Ubuntu 16.04
aws region: us-east-1
aws-java-sdk: "1.11.723"
```